# Calling simple method in if-statement

Tags: objective-c, methods

I'm still getting the objective c way, have done some progress, but I'm stuck in some stupid dilemma:

I need to call a method in an if,

```
if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 1"])
{
  [self mensage1];
}
```

the method

```
void mensage1() 
{
    NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
}
```

also I declared in *.h

```
-(void) mensage1;
```

Obviously is not working well. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared an Objective-C method but you defined a C function.

What you want is:

```
- (void)mensage1
{
    NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
}
```

Comment: tnx, yeah I come from embedded C, learning this stuff now, cheers, I still got an error bro,

Answer (score 2):

Your method definition is wrong, but your declaration is correct, simply copy it to your implementation file and strip the semicolon:

```
- (void) mensage1
{
   NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
}
```

What you defined in your `.m` file is a C *function*, not an Objective-C method.

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely hard to understand what you're trying to ask.
First of all, how exactly is it not working?

Is the if statement not working? Or is the mensage1() method not being called?

Comment: It's not working because he's mixing languages. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well , this is not the answer, just the continuation of the question,,,
if I do

```
void mensage1 
{
NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
}
```

I get an error> Expected = , ; asm or *attribute* before { token

also , si the call to the function ok in the if?? [self mensage1]; ??

Comment: (1) In the future, please don't answer your own question to add information. Edit your original question. (2) Look closely at what I posted and what you posted. What you posted is neither compilable C nor Objective-C. The first line should be `- (void) mensage1`

Comment: ok!!! its working, sorry, I must be getting tired hhahaha, cheers, thanks for the lesson on syntax  and netiquette! ;)